# c#: Choosing or modifying a control to create draggable graphics on a canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, wpf-controls

I'm attempting to write a small app that will do something similar to what is shown here:

http://www.soccertutor.com/tour/MASTER_SKIN_team.swf

However I've not used WPF/Win Forms very much at all and can't seem to find a control that will be most applicable to the situation. I want to have some sort of grid for the pitch so I can have players, cones, other items snap to certain parts of the grid and I would like the players to be draggable onto the various grid squares.

Thanks very much, I look forward to hearing your recommendations/suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use controls for something like this.  You use objects in your code that represent a visible item on the screen.  Periodically you render an update to the screen.  You draw the background, then each object.  You add mouse hit testing to make the scene interactive to the user.  The main game loop calculates new object positions, implements object collision detection and game rules.

Comment: So you think the best way to go about this would be to draw everything as paths etc. ?? This seems very tedious.

Comment: Yes, game programming can be very tedious.  Look at something like XNA to take the tedium out of it.